# Im trying to use a function to put every 3 characters of a text file into one pointer of arrays.

Tags: c

I have a pointer of char* array. One part of my program's going to read a text file, get char1 2 3 and store it in array[0]. Then, instead of reading 4 5 6, i want my program to read 2 3 4, 3 4 5, and so on until the word finishes, skip the space and continues with the second word. Should I still use fgetc? Any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: "I have a pointer of char* array. One part of my program's going to read a text file" --> best to post your code.

Comment: Just call read() function as long as you have not read the entire file. read() return the number of characters it reads, so, to get every 3 characters you have to check if: return_value % 3 == 0. Then get the current char and put it in your array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[UPDATE]
You have to :

- Read all the file and put its content in char*
- Parse the string, get the current character and check if the 2 next characters are defined
- Put it in your array (here I just display with printf)

Here is an example:

```
int             main(int ac, char **av)
{
  int           fd;
  char          *str;
  int           size;
  int           i;
  struct stat   sb;

  i = -1;
  if (ac != 2)
    return (84);
  if (!(fd = open(av[1], O_RDONLY)))
    return (84);
  if (stat(av[1], &sb) == -1)
    return (84);
  size = sb.st_size; // Get the size of the file
  if (!(str = malloc(sizeof(char) * (size + 1)))) // Allocate enought memory
    return (84);
  if (read(fd, str, size) == -1) // Read all the file
    return (84);
  str[size + 1] = 0;

  // Parse the string to get characters you're looking for
  while (str[++i])
    {
      printf("%c", str[i]);
      if (str[i + 1])
        {
          printf("%c", str[i + 1]);
          if (str[i + 2])
            printf("%c", str[i + 2]);
        }
      printf("\n");
    }
  free(str);
  return (0);
}
```

My file is just like: `123456789ABCDEFGHIJKL`

And this is my output:

```
123
234
345
456
567
678
789
89A
9AB
ABC
BCD
CDE
DEF
EFG
FGH
GHI
HIJ
IJK
JKL
KL
L
```

Is it what you're looking for ?

Comment: but this is only getting one character, skips 3, and gets another one. I want to get every three characters (0 1 2) and the next time starting from (1 2 3)

Comment: Oh okay sorry, I didn't understand. I think the best way is to read all the file and put its content in a string, and then, parse the string with a variable ('i' for example) and catch str[i], str[i + 1], str[i + 2] before increment the variable (i++);

Answer (score 0):

like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 3
#define MAX_WORDS 100

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {   
    char *array[MAX_WORDS];
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    int buf_pos = 0;

    FILE *fp = stdin;

    int word_count = 0;
    int ch;
    while(word_count < MAX_WORDS && (ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF){
        if(isspace(ch))
            continue;//skip whitespaces
        buffer[buf_pos++ % BUFFER_SIZE] = ch;
        if(buf_pos >= BUFFER_SIZE){
            array[word_count] = calloc(1, sizeof(BUFFER_SIZE+1));//check omitted
            for(int i = 0; i < BUFFER_SIZE; ++i){
                array[word_count][i] = buffer[(buf_pos+i) % BUFFER_SIZE];
            }
            ++word_count;
        }
    }
    if(0 < buf_pos && buf_pos < BUFFER_SIZE){//if not fill buffer
        array[0] = malloc(sizeof(BUFFER_SIZE+1));//The size was made constant
        memcpy(array[0], buffer, buf_pos);
        array[word_count++][buf_pos] = 0;
    }
    fclose(fp);

    for(int i = 0; i < word_count; ++i){
        printf("%s\n", array[i]);
        free(array[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```